# How to get the position of the last visible item inside an Adapter in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I intend to create a listview with different layout for each **visible** row. I also set `setStackFromBottom(true)`.

I know I can use `int getItemViewType(int position)` in `View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` but it uses the fix position and not based on visible positions.

I'd like to use the listview as the following concept shows:

[image: listview order]

If I scroll down, the next item should replace the previous one and use its large layout. 
I tried it with the following code, but it uses fix position so always the *last item in the list* is the largest, not the *last visible item*.

```
 @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position)
  {
    if(position==values.length-1)
      return 1;
    return 0;
  }

 @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = null;
    type=getItemViewType(position);
    if (type == 0)
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    else
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, parent, false);
    return rowView;
  }
```

I reckon, I should get the position of the first and last visible item inside the Adapter, but I don't know how to do it.

Can I somehow create a listview that follows the aforementioned concept? Can I get the correct positions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a lot of info by setting a scroll listener on the ListView:

```
mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount = last item
    }
}
```

However, I can't think of how you could use this info effectively.  Even if you change getView() to return a larger View when its position is the same as the last item, you can't easily resize the views as they move up, because getView() won't be called again for items already displayed, unless you call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter repeatedly, which would kill performance.

My though is to add another View below the ListView that will display the larger View for the item below the last one in the ListView.  Make it look like the last row in the ListView.  You could change that view in the onScroll() method.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to update each row on scroll, as they "scroll down" and the largest one disappears and the one above gets its layout and so on to the top. I need something that dynamically changes each row.

Comment: That's beyond me.  I think you would have to create your own custom list view and do the drawing (onDraw()) manually.

Comment: I'm afraid so. I've never done that so I don't know yet how I can do that concept.

Comment: Well, that is how you get the position of the last visible item anyway.

Comment: Yes, I get the last position. Now I use ´invalidateViews´ to force the listView to be redrawn. It is almost good, but it is flickering. I wonder what I should do about that.